# What does "Nonstandard output" mean on Tradeblock transaction page?

Tags: electrum, confirmations, output

I tried to send bitcoin but the recipient hasn't received it.

The trade block page shows "Nonstandard output" under outputs as shown in the link below:

[Tradeblock page for transaction](https://tradeblock.com/bitcoin/tx/5b343128dd48c851d2db267270fb2665ae0fcb95d00fe3b5525a1f8c25e315c7)

I used an Electrum wallet and the transaction seemed to confirm as the usual green tick appeared next to it in the transaction history. However my balance was 0BTC and the text "not enough funds" appeared in the bottom left corner.

What's going on? How do I either get my money to the recipient or back to me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A bitcoin address that starts with bc1 is a bech32 address. It is possible that Tradblock hasn't been updated to cater for this type of address.

Other Blockchain explorers show the transaction as confirmed.

Comment: the bc1... address isn't the one that I sent it to. That starts with 3Cn. How could this have happened?

Comment: This answer helped me hone in on the real problem using question: https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/84709/bitcoin-automatically-diverted-to-bech32-address/84710#84710. Turns out it's a phishing attack.