# Bitcoin automatically diverted to bech32 address

Tags: security, electrum, fraud, bech32-address, revert-transaction

I sent bitcoin to an address starting 3Cn using Electrum but the blockchain viewers seem to show that it has gone to an address beginning bc1 as shown in the link below.

[Transaction Viewer](https://www.blockchain.com/btc/tx/5b343128dd48c851d2db267270fb2665ae0fcb95d00fe3b5525a1f8c25e315c7?show_adv=true)

How can this happen? Is there a way I can recover the funds?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

I'm sorry to be the bearer of bad news: It looks like your funds are gone and the security of your computer is compromised. A quick google suggests that is one of the [electrum phishing destination addresses](https://blog.coinbase.com/electrohunt-part-1-hunting-for-the-phishing-campaigns-on-the-electrum-network-b10529162e63).

You can find more information on the attacks against electrum here: http://electrum-malware.surge.sh/

Comment: Your links have reminded me that Electrum did in fact ask me to update it in order to complete the transaction. Thanks for pointing this out.

Comment: @S.B: Electrum most likely didn't. Rather some phisher did.

Comment: @R.. Yes. Indeed.